# Graficar correctamente usando matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Tengo que hacer una serie de gráficas y no consigo aprender a usar matplotlib bien.

A decir verdad, el código que pongo a continuación funciona correctamente, pero tengo grandes dudas de que no se pueda hacer mejor, más sencillo.

```
no_low, maybe, no_up = [[0,2,6],[1,1,0]], [[5,7,15,17],[0,1,1,0]], [[16,19,25], [0,1,1]]
labels = [no_low, maybe, no_up]
# Gráfica
plt.figure(figsize=(5,3))
plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
plt.plot(labels[0][0], labels[0][1], labels[1][0], labels[1][1], labels[2][0], labels[2][1])
plt.xlabel('Área px')
plt.title('Función de pertenencia - ÁREA')
plt.legend(('No', 'Quizás', 'No'), loc=0)
plt.xlim(0,25)
plt.ylim(0,1.1)
```

Tengo mis dudas sobretodo en esta línea `plt.plot(labels[0][0], labels[0][1], labels[1][0], labels[1][1], labels[2][0], labels[2][1])`, pues para mi lo lógico sería poner algo similar a esto `plt.plot(labels)` pero no va. Lo cual me hace pensar si ya me he complicado a la hora de declarar las listas de coordenadas.

¿Alguien sabe como mejorarlo?

Un saludo y salud para todos.

Answer (score 2):

El método `plot`(si quieres graficar varias lineas simultáneamente en una sola llamada) espera una pareja de iterables con las mismas dimensiones por cada línea, especificando las coordenadas de cada punto, el primero con los valores del eje `X` y el segundo con los de `Y` para dichos puntos, es decir algo como:

```
plt.plot((Ax, Bx, Cx), (Ay, By, Cy), [fmt], (Dx, Ex), (Dy, Ey), [fmt], ...)
```

donde los puntos `A`, `B` y `C` formarían una línea y los puntos `D` y `E` otra.

`fmt` es la cadena con el formato para esa linea (como `'ro--'`, `'g^'`, etc), es opcional y se intercala después de cada pareja de iterables con los puntos `X` e `Y` para cada linea.

Para simplificar lo que puedes hacer es usar el operador `*` para desempaquetar las listas:

```
labels = [*no_low, *maybe, *no_up]
plt.plot(*labels)
```

o directamente:

```
plt.plot(*no_low, *maybe, *no_up)
```

Si tuvieras por un casual una lista `labels` con la estructura que muestras y no dependiera de ti modificarla o no quieras hacerlo solo para `plot`, puedes usar una expresión generadora que itere sobre las lista de listas  y pueda ir generando los argumentos tal cómo el método los espera sin crear una lista o contenedor intermedio:

```
labels = [no_low, maybe, no_up]
plt.plot(*(coord for label in labels for coord in label))
```

la otra opción obvia es usar un ciclo y múltiples llamadas a `matplotlib.pyplot.plot`:

```
labels = [no_low, maybe, no_up]
for label in labels:
    plt.plot(*label)
```

Que sería equivalente en este caso a:

```
for label in labels:
    plt.plot(label[0], label[1])
```

o más bonito y eficiente, dejar el desempaquetado al ciclo:

```
for x, y in labels:
    plt.plot(x, y)
```

Efectivamente, podría aceptar directamente la lista `labels` con este formato, pero eso es algo que no está en nuestras manos, no sin reimplementar el método claro. El hacerlo así tiene sus ventajas y sus desventajas, como todo.